Error while querying superset with drill data connection
I am facing an issue while querying Superset with a Drill data connection. I am using Drill with Zookeeper (connected to Zookeeper using the service port).
When I query Drill directly, the connections are fine, and results are produced. However, when I add the connection from Superset to Drill, I can see the schemas from the database, but when I select a table, I encounter the following error:

Apache Drill Error
AUTH <password> called without any password configured for the default user. Are you sure your configuration is correct?

I have followed some steps to create a configmap but was unable to configure the drill-override.conf file correctly. Here is what I attempted:
security.user.auth: {
enabled: true,
packages: [ "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security" ],
impl: "pam4j",
pam_profiles: [ "sshd" ],
users: {
    "admin": {
    "password": "admin1"
      }
   }
 }}

And expected to find the user configurations in  drill-override.conf
